# Regularity of solutions to forward-backward stochastic differential equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose $X_t$, $P_t$ and $Z_t$ are one dimension random processes and satisfy
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
d X_t
&= aP_t dt +bdB_t;\\
X_0
&= x_0;\\
d P_t
&=cP_t dt + c^*Z_t dB_t;
\\
P_T
&= eX_T;
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
for some real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $c^*$, $e$ and $x_0$. I know that the solution $(X_t,P_t,Z_t)$ is in the $L^2$ space with bounded norm $\|(X_t,P_t,Z_t)\|^2 = \mathbb{E}\left(\int^T_0|X_s|^2+|P_s|^2+|Z_s|^2ds\right)<\infty$ by standard result. Can I improve the result such that the solution has the property that
$$ \mathbb{E}\left(\sup_{s \in [0,T]}|X_s|^2+\sup_{s \in [0,T]}|P_s|^2+\int^T_0|Z_s|^2ds\right)<\infty ?$$

Comment: Any more details for Zt? It seems that (Pt,Zt) is a "separate" process that we can first study as an Ito-like process. Usually the way one gets bound for expected of suprema is via chaining arguments eg. see Theorem 6.16 (Fernique) in  https://web.math.princeton.edu/~rvan/APC550.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually, I find a theorem about that, Theorem 4.12 and definition for      solutions to FBSDE in page 216, in "Probabilistic Theory of Mean Field Games with Applications I". I think it solves my problem, isn't it?